# Scratch image to fill div with aspect ratio or limit dimensions if image is bigger than div

Tags: html, css, image, height, width

I have a div of dimensions 630x630px. Now I want to place an image inside this div. If image is larger than 630px (it's width or height) I can simply use max-width and max-height and it will be fitted to 630px. But what if image is smaller than 630px? In that case I would like this image's larger dimension to be stretched with constant aspect ratio to 630px. How can I do it?

Comment: take a look at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `object-fit` and `object-position` CSS properties on the image to achieve this. Your code should look like this:

```
.container {
  width: 630px;
  height: 630px;
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using `position: absolute;` when it's unnecessary.
`object-fit` does the trick by itself.

```css
.container {
  width: 630px;
  height: 630px;
  
  /* To visualize better the behavior of the image */
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/1200x1000" alt="">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/150x80" alt="">
</div>
```